# How can I put a logo image in the middle of bootstrap fixed nav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am trying to create a website using bootstrap and I have used bootstrap before. This time I am making a site with a fixed nav and the logo will be in the middle of the nav links. I also want the logo to be on top of the nav links.

This image will show what I am trying to do:

[image]

The code I have now is this:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', serif;
}

.navbar {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;

}

.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;

}

.fourth-color {
  background-color: #ffecec;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.third-color {
  background-color: #122212;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.second-color {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.first-color {
  background-color: #f25727;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start of Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul>
      <li class="first-color"><a href="#">First</a></li>
      <li class="second-color"><a href="#">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
      <li class="third-color"><a href="#">Third</a></li>
      <li class="fourth-color"><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When I try to link an image, it doesn't fit properly and screws with the whole nav bar. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is you only have padding on the li's that have classes. (which is why the anchor that says logo is not centered is because it doesn't have a class with padding)

ex.

```
.navbar ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.fourth-color, .third-color, .second-color, .first-color {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Apply the padding to all the lists and you're problem is fixed.

```
.navbar ul li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

As for the middle logo. You have to use `position relative` and then add your additional styles to that either by class or in my case `:nth-child` as seen below.

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&subset=latin,latin-ext");

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', serif;
}

.navbar {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(20% - 1px - 0.906752000000002em);
  padding: 1.16em 1em;
  font: 100 21px "Raleway", sans-serif;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.navbar li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ff410e;
}

.navbar li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f4ca00;
}

.navbar li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2.84em;
  padding: 1.76em 0;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  margin: -0.64em -2.16em;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar li:nth-child(3) a {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #99d81b;
}

.navbar li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #00abf3;
}

.navbar li:hover:not(:nth-child(3)) {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar .active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start of Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Unless you plan on creating a dropdown list I wouldn't recommend using a list for this menubar. Instead [you can just style the anchors to fit your needs](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#0873d7f82d37b9824e7426d3ce6e88ff). (Remember to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

Comment: Ok, so I've done that and got it centered. However, when I do add an image where I will want my logo to be, it comes lower than the nav bar. Also, the real image way be a bit wider to look like the design in the imgur link I provided.

Comment: I have made this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZwVpL) to show what I am talking about.  Yeah, I don't think I will be using drop down lists, so that idea does look better. Can I add the image logo the way I want using that method?

Comment: I understand now. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I've updated my answer and hope it fits your needs. BTW  I'm on my tablet so I'm using [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#0873d7f82d37b9824e7426d3ce6e88ff) (Jade/Stylus preprocessors) in order to answer faster.

Comment: Thank You so much for the help! I will try it out with my logo and let you know how it goes. Also, sorry for the formatting issues, I will read up on them before asking my next question on the site.

Comment: Remember! This is not a code dump site! I answered your original question and went a little further out of courtesy. If you have another problem ask another question related to the specific problem.